# My application turns all "1" digits to red color like voodoo magic

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, colors

In my application all the "1" digits are turned to red!

[image]

[image]

This only happens with this application (Is not a hardware error), but I'm sure I did nothing in the code of this application to get this strange problem!

I don't know which piece of code I can post to get help 'cause like I've said I did NOTHING.

My question is why I get that red colored ones, This is the full source: http://ElektroStudios.tk/WinampToFolder.zip

Comment: Looks ok to me. It just looks like *really* bad clear text rendering

Comment: Could it be that you're using a monitor that uses BGR subpixel order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not your application. Play with ClearType settings in Control Panel to get rid of this effect..

Answer (score 1):

When I first looked at the images, the 1s looked solid white to me. I had to squint and get closer to the screen to see a hint of red in them. My guess is you're using an LCD screen, like me, and this is a case of bad [sub-pixel rendering](https://www.grc.com/ctwhat.htm). Or maybe you have [synesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia) :)